# stream with pi zero NOIR camera

Tags: video, streaming

I have used this and other very similar from web sites but all result in a syntax error with the carat symbol below the `m` of a stream.  This has happened each time I produce a script from whatever source.

can somebody help me?

Thonny ide
Pi zero (w)

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 |cvlc -v stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8554}' :demux=h264
```

Comment: You cannot use linux commands directly in python. You need to use Python functions to call these commands or call them from a command line (terminal window) instead of Thonny.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response -I want to run a script in the pi Zero and then view it from VLC in a browser.   This what others were doing with this script.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As I was trying to explain: you are trying to run a Linux command from a Python IDE. That will not work. Try to enter the command in a terminal window.